# Angular2 / dynamic modal popup

Tags: angular, popupwindow

I (try to) learn c# and angular and want to display a detail modal popup if a user click on a div.

If possible it would be great if I can transmit the detaildata directly from the ngfor loop into the "popup" window. If not I can give a Id for a new web.api call to this function.

Does anyone has a good and easy example? I tried to use primeng (does not work unfortunately with my angular 2.4 - I got several errors), I tried ng2-bs3-modal - this destroyed my running application too and seems not to work with angular 2.4 too :( ). So I removed it all.

Thanks a lot
Ralf

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [angular2-modal](https://github.com/shlomiassaf/angular2-modal)

Here's an example I made where you can pass data from an `ngFor` into the modal popup by creating a custom modal: [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/w3tV4Wqu2rgNfjHIlWQu?p=preview)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your recommendation. I try to install thi modal and followed the installation (only first without "Configure root element") - but now my app does not start: (index):30 ZoneAwareError {__zone_symbol__error: Error: (SystemJS) Unexpected token <
 SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
     at eval (<anonymous>)
   …, __zone_symbol__stack: "(SystemJS) Unexpected token <↵ SyntaxError: Unexpe… Error loading http://localhost:14062/app/main.js", originalErr: SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
    at eval (<anonymous>)
    at SystemJSLoader.__exec

Comment: In visual studio I got now nearly 900 errors in 
G:\test\src\WebApplication2\node_modules\@types\core-js\index.d.ts
G:\test\src\WebApplication2\typings\globals\core-js\index.d.ts
like this:
TS2300 Duplicate identifier 'PropertyKey'. TypeScript Virtual TS2323 Cannot redeclare exported variable 'Array'. TypeScript Virtual Projects

Comment: I solved this now without modal - only (click)="onSelect(item)" and a  <template [ngIf]= . Modal did not work and took me many hours and just did not run :(  I hope google implement a easy way without other components.